# JS - How can I set a div's width and height from an input value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm creating a box using JavaScript and then I want to set said box's width and height using two form inputs, one for width and one for height. I can't seem to make that happen.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<form action="" id="theForm">
    <label for="width">Box Width: </label>
    <input type="text" id="width" name="width">

    <label for="height">Box Height: </label>
    <input type="text" id="height" name="height">

    <input type="submit" value="Create Box" id="submit-btn">
</form>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
var form = document.getElementById("theForm"),
    box = document.createElement("div");

    document.body.appendChild(box);

form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    var width = form.elements["width"].value,
        height = form.elements["height"].value;

    box.style.width = width + "px";
    box.style.height = height + "px";
});
```

Seems to work fine when I set the width and height manually but not when I try to get it from the input. 
I'm pretty new to JS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add another line of code //return false// at the end of the event listener you defined for the form @aroundsix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably agree with @epascarello's answer, but instead of returning false, i'd use `preventDefault();`

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) { // Don't forget to pass the 'e' parameter
  var width = form.elements["width"].value,
    height = form.elements["height"].value;

  box.style.width = width + "px";
  box.style.height = height + "px";

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Using `preventDefault` will prevent the default behavior of the event beeing passed, which is the form submit.

You can use it with links and other stuffs too.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing cause using return false only made it appear for a fraction of a second. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The form submits so the page refreshes. You need to cancel the form submission.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("theForm"),
    box = document.createElement("div");

    document.body.appendChild(box);

form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    var width = form.elements["width"].value,
        height = form.elements["height"].value;

    box.style.width = width + "px";
    box.style.height = height + "px";
  
    return false;
});
```

```css
div { background-color: #CFC; }
```

```html
<form action="" id="theForm">
    <label for="width">Box Width: </label>
    <input type="text" id="width" name="width">

    <label for="height">Box Height: </label>
    <input type="text" id="height" name="height">

    <input type="submit" value="Create Box" id="submit-btn">
</form>
```

Comment: I can see it flash for a second and then it disappears if i use return false; However if I use event.preventDeafault(); it works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with one change: adding `return false;` to the handler, so the submit doesn't go through and re-load the page.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("theForm");

var box = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(box);

form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  var width = form.elements["width"].value,
    height = form.elements["height"].value;

  box.style.width = width + "px";
  box.style.height = height + "px";
  box.style.border = "1px solid red";  // for demo visibility purposes
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="theForm">
  <label for="width">Box Width:</label>
  <input type="text" id="width" name="width">

  <label for="height">Box Height:</label>
  <input type="text" id="height" name="height">

  <input type="submit" value="Create Box" id="submit-btn">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works great with event.preventDefault(); Can't believe I didn't think of this on my own.